# Regression discontinuity and regression to the mean

Tags: regression, experiment-design, causality, regression-discontinuity

Regression discontinuity designs aren't susceptible to regression to the mean. I'm not quite sure why, though. The best I can come up with is that regression to the mean is a phenomenon that occurs because you're dealing with a sample measured at different points, which have different underlying distributions at each point. With RD designs, however, you're measuring the difference in intercept along a column separating two smooth regression functions within a single bivariate distribution.

Can anyone shed further light on this?

Comment: Have a look at here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86019/regression-discontinuity-design-parametric-versus-non-parametric-different-resul